# A set is called sequential - closed if it contains all its sequential limit point.

Tags: general-topology

A set is called sequential-closed if it contains all its sequential limit point.

A set is called sequential-open if it is a sequential neighborhood ($N$ is a sequential neighborhood if whenever $x_n$ converge to $x$, $x_n \in N$ eventually).

Is complement of sequential-open, sequential-closed ?

Comment: What are your own thoughts on this? What do you know about the relation between closedness and sequential closedness?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Let $X$ be a space and $U$ a sequentially open subset of $X$. Suppose that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a sequence in $X\setminus U$ that converges to a point $x\in X$. Is it possible for $x$ to belong to the set $U$? Remember, $U$ is sequentially open.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start the proof (and actually write the main bulk) for you.

Let $U$ be a sequential-open subset of the metric space $X$ and consider its complemenet $V=X\setminus U$. Suppose that $V$ is not sequential-closed - that is, suppose there exists some limit point $x_V\in X$ of $V$ such that $x_V$ is not in $V$. Well, if $x_V$ is not in $V$, then we must have $x_V\in U$. As $x_V$ is a limit point of $V$, there exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 0}$ such that $(x_n)_{n\geq 0}\to x_V$...

Can you see how to continue this argument to reach a contradiction?